# jquery select2 and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried `jQuery` `select2`

```
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
```

and it is working as intended.

However, my select has over 700 options and i don't want to load them before the user wishes to use the select box.

so, i am trying to show the select box only when the user clicks on a button.

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Load of Script</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="showselect">
        <button onclick="showselect()">select category</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function showselect() { 
            document.getElementById('showselect').innerHTML='loading...';
            $('#showselect').load('select1.htm');
            $.getScript("select2.js");
            $(".chzn").select2({width:230});
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`select1.htm` contains the css style as well as the select form html code :

```
http://likeforums.com/select1.htm
```

`select2.js` is taken from select2 script and it is here :

```
http://likeforums.com/select2.js
```

The result is here :

```
http://likeforums.com/test-select3.htm
```

When clicked on the button, it is just showing the select box and `select2` is not working.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Call `select2()` after the script is successfully loaded and executed. Check for the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, call `select2()` after the script is successfully loaded and executed.
So put

```
$(".chzn").select2({width:230});
```

In the callback for `getScript()` function as:

```
function showselect() { 
    document.getElementById('showselect').innerHTML='loading...';
    $('#showselect').load('select1.htm');
    $.getScript("select2.js",function() {
       $(".chzn").select2({width:230});
   });
}
```

Here is the documentation [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

No need to load it hide it on `document.ready` and show it on `button` `click`

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#listid").hide();
    $("#buttonid").click(function(){    
        $("#listid").show();
    });
});
```

after that write jquery to show the data in select list for that you need to write the jquery for list in click event

```
$("#listid").click(function(){
    //Write code to bind the data 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since the first reply worked, I haven't tried your suggestion. Sorry!